# EF4.3 Code-First, MVC, Lazy Loading After Attaching in POST Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading, model-binding

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3 with Code-First in an MVC 3 application. I have a POST action that gets an entity as its' parameter, and then marks the entity as modified to update the database. It's a Document entity that has a reference to a File Type.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Example(Document model)
 {
     // fileType is null, as expected
     var fileType = model.FileType;

     // attach and mark the entity as modified, save changes
     Context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
     Context.SaveChanges();

     // fileType is still null?
     fileType = model.FileType;

     return View(model);
 }
```

After attaching an entity to the context, shouldn't I be able to lazy-load properties on that entity?

Interestingly, when I try this in a console application it seems to work.

```
static void Main()
{
    // create a new context
    var context = new Context();

    // get the first document and detach it
    var doc = context.Documents.First();
    context.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Detached;

    // fileType is null, as expected
    var fileType = doc.FileType;

    // dispose and create a new context
    context.Dispose();
    context = new Context();

    // attach the entity and mark it as modified
    context.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // fileType is not null, which is the desired outcome
    fileType = doc.FileType;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the entity passed to the post method is not a proxy, presumably because it was created outside of the Entity Framewortk using the normal "new" operator.

There are a few options here. First, you could modify the MVC controller to create proxy instances by using the `DbSet.Create` method.  I've heard it is possible to modify the MVC controller in this way, but never tried it myself. For example, instead of doing:

```
var doc = new Document();
```

in the controller, you would do:

```
var doc = context.Documents.Create();
```

The create method lets EF create a proxy for lazy loading, if the entity has appropriate virtual properties, which in your case it looks like it does.

A second and potentially easier option is to not use lazy loading but instead use the explicit loading APIs. For example, to load FileType:

```
var fileType = context.Entry(doc).Reference(d => d.FileType).Load();
```

Unlikely lazy loading, this needs an explicit reference to the context, but in your case that should be okay.

Comment: Thanks! Using your explanation I was able to find an easy solution for implementing a model binder that generates proxies. Here is a link to the article that helped me. http://bit.ly/ydCjOm